# Does the following dialogue sound stiff and formal?

Tags: fiction, creative-writing, dialogue

This is a dialogue from a short story I'm writing:

> Finally, a log caught fire, followed by the rest. And in no time Paola
>   and I had a display of dancing flames before us, their warmth entering
>   every pore of our skin.
>
> "You're pretty good." Paola looked genuinely impressed.
>
> "I used to do it a lot," I explained, "when I was a kid."
>
> "I see. I think it's nice—having a skill."
>
> "Building a fire isn't a very useful one."
>
> "It's still nice, though." Paola gazed thoughtfully at the flames, as
>   though trying to find a hidden meaning in their glow. "A skill that
>   has nothing to do with money. I think it's more simple, more pure. And
>   you do it just because you enjoy it. Sometimes we forget to do things
>   just for the sheer pleasure of it."
>
> "Um. Never thought of it that way . . ." I was surprised. Paola had
>   suddenly become more talkative. That's when I realized I had no idea
>   what was crossing her mind. I might as well have been peering into the
>   murky water of a swamp.
>
> Once the fire died down a bit, we took out the grill net and started
>   working on the barbecue. Not that there was a lot to prepare. The
>   things we bought at the supermarket—the chicken pieces, the diced
>   beef, the sausages, the pepper and onions—were already seasoned. All
>   we had to do was to slide them onto the skewers and throw them on the
>   grill.
>
> While we waited for the meat to cook, we sat side by side, drinking
>   the beers we brought along. It was already dark, and the only light on
>   the beach was our improvised fire. Now and then, a piece of wood would
>   fall off, sending millions of sparks around. Short-lived fireflies
>   fluttering under a darkened sky.
>
> "Uh, Paola?" This was the best moment to bring it up. "Can I ask you
>   something?"
>
> Paola held her can in mid-air. "Sure."
>
> "Why did you decide to come? I mean, even though the rest backed
>   out—including Natalia. She's the only one in the group you know, isn't
>   she? Please don't take it in a bad way. I'm just curious."
>
> "You think it's weird?"
>
> "Well . . . just a little bit. We don't know each other after all."
>
> "I figured you wouldn't try anything funny. Oh, are you that kind of
>   guy? I warn you, if you try something I'll chop your dick off and feed
>   it to the fish."
>
> "Wow," I said, "no need for that. You just killed a week's worth of
>   boners with that one."
>
> We both laughed. I could feel the atmosphere
>   relax, become warmer. And it wasn't just because of the fire.
>
> Paola said, "Joking aside, I came to visit my mom."
>
> "Your mom?"
>
> Paola nodded. A drop of fat fell into the fire, creating a flame that
>   illuminated the rocks nearby for a couple of seconds.
>
> "Sorry," I said, "I don't follow."
>
> "She disappeared long ago in the sea." Paola took a sip of her beer.
>   "Not here, in Viña. I was eleven at the time. Mom was teaching me to
>   swim when this huge wave came up and crashed against us. A really big
>   one. The size of a skyscraper." A deep crease formed between her
>   brows. "After that, I don't remember much—just that I was surrounded
>   by this mess of water, panic, and bubbles. Then total darkness. When I
>   woke up I was in a hospital bed. My father had rescued me. As for my
>   mom . . . he couldn’t find her, nor could the rescue crew. She just
>   vanished under that wave.”
>
> I stared at Paola. I didn't know what to say. And I felt a simple “I'm
>   sorry” wouldn't be enough, so I stayed quiet.
>
> She continued, "Anyway, that’s why I’m here. Since I’m moving to
>   Santiago after graduation, I wanted to visit the sea one last time, to
>   say goodbye to Mom."
>
> "But I don't understand,” I said. “Why here? You
>   said the . . . the incident, happened in Viña."
>
> "All the oceans are connected, you know? They are, in fact, a single
>   mass of water that goes all over the globe. So, no matter where you
>   drown, you immediately become part of that wholeness."

Does it sound stiff and formal at times? If so, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points that got kinda stiff for me as a reader and as a writer were when you split a sentence with a dialogue tag.

For example,

> "I used to do it a lot," I explained, "when I was a kid."
>
> "Wow," I said, "no need for that.

However, the dialogue you split with action tags was fantastic.

> "Uh, Paola?" This was the best moment to bring it up. "Can I ask you something?"

Among many others so well done.

A few points below sounded awkward.

> She continued, "Anyway, that’s why I’m here.
>
> Paola said, "Joking aside, I came to visit my mom."

Re-word those with a description of some sort and they'll fit right into your scene. Content-wise your dialogue felt natural, honestly. Not stiff in the slightest.